# ECDSA: Why do ssh-keygen and Java generated public keys have different sizes?

Tags: ssh, java

I am using `ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -b 256`
which generates this for the public part:

```
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTItbmlzdHAyNTYAAAAIbmlzdHAyNTYAAABBBNaHgNjXShzF/hmZOuhTCCsokgpSCyFohETHT4+OQMxW5g+d9nZCYxpDhwivuWbsoXTYpQWlLATXxjbQr2Y3KRY= t0132456@L541918
```

I need to do the same in Java. I am using BouncyCastle:

```
ECParameterSpec ecSpec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("secp256r1");
KeyPairGenerator g = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA", "BC");
g.initialize(ecSpec, new SecureRandom());
KeyPair pair = g.generateKeyPair();

ECPublicKey publicKey = (ECPublicKey)pair.getPublic();
System.out.println("kpub=" + Base64.toBase64String(publicKey.getEncoded()));
```

but the public key is smaller and does not start with same header:

```
kpub=MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEvHW0nR1hAzy3BuQR8mMkHqgGvvdXLZWAXS29fkFbhshr8y6xybHh0LRDoaUciYgr3w7WGKpfxFSSFqSjdG8bww==
```

How to be generate the same way ssh-genkey does but in Java?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sizes are different because the formats are different. The strings you show are both binary values encoded in [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). In all this message I talk about the binary values, i.e. I suppose that you first decoded the Base64 strings into binary.

Mathematically, an ECDSA public key is a point on an elliptic curve. A point has two coordinates, called *X* and *Y*, which are bound to each other through the curve equation (in that case, *Y*<sup>2</sup> = *X*<sup>3</sup> + *aX* + *b* for two constants *a* and *b* that define the specific curve). Here, you use the NIST P-256 curve, which has been specified to work in a 256-bit field, i.e. *X* and *Y* are two 256-bit integers. The [ANSI X9.62 standard](http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=ANSI%20X9.62%3A2005) defines a 65-byte format for representing such *X* and *Y*; basically, a first byte of value 0x04, followed by *X* over exactly 32 bytes (in big-endian notation), then *Y* over another 32 bytes.

So far so good. Then both Java and SSH wrap that 65-byte value into a structure that also identifies explicitly the curve itself through some symbolic identifiers. They do so differently.

Java follows the ASN.1-based encoding also specified in ANSI X9.62. There are several options, but, in your case, you got a `SEQUENCE` whose contents are a nested sub-`SEQUENCE`, then a `BIT STRING`. The nested sub-`SEQUENCE` contains two `OBJECT IDENTIFIER` values, the first one being 1.2.840.10045.2.1 (which means "this is an elliptic curve public key"), and the second is 1.2.840.10045.3.1.7, which designates the NIST P-256 curve. The `BIT STRING` contents are, exactly, the 65-byte encoding of the curve point. To make the story short: the Java value, when Base64-decoded, yields a value of length 91 bytes, the last 65 bytes of which being the encoding of *X* and *Y*.

OpenSSH, on the other hand, is well-known for a chronic allergy to standards, and of course they invented their own format. It has been then documented in [RFC 5656, section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5656#section-3.1). Basically, the encoded key consists in three "strings", one after the other. Each string consists in a 32-bit header (4 bytes, big-endian notation) followed by the string value; the header contains the value length, in bytes. The first string is the ASCII encoding of "ecdsa-sha2-nistp256" (this is identifies the signature algorithm). The second string is the ASCII encoding of "nistp256" (this identifies the curve, redundantly with the first string). The third string has a 65-byte value, and, you guessed it, that's the 65-byte encoding of *X* and *Y*. The total length is 104 bytes, and the *X* and *Y* encoding uses the last 65 of these 104 bytes.

---

So basically, in both formats, the interesting part is exactly the last 65 bytes; the rest is just an identifier for the involved curve, in two distinct dialects. If you generate many keys with `ssh-keygen`, you will notice that they will differ only in their last 65 bytes (there again, *after* Base64 decoding). Similarly with producing many keys in Java.

Therefore, converting from a Java-produced public key to a SSH-compatible public key is as simply as taking the last 65 bytes of that key (after Base64 decoding, where applicable), and concatenating these after the 39-byte header of a SSH key.

Comment: I wish all answers were this complete. Outstanding

Comment: Thanks for this detailled and very well explained answer.

Comment: The link to the SEC1 paper in the RFC doesn't work anymore. Here's one that works: http://www.secg.org/SEC1-Ver-1.0.pdf (and no, the site sadly doesn't have HTTPS)